# Bootstrap 3 div auto width not 100% of parent div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make a div for showing content in a small box. I want the div to be auto width but it is always going 100% of the parent div, is div maybe not the best way?

```
<div class="rental-feature">
    <span class="feature-icon door"></span>
    <span class="feature-text">2222222</span>
</div>
```

Here is a link to an image of what I am trying to do, the content in feature text should control the width. But when I make it as is, the code always goes to 100% of the parent div.

[image]

Comment: please provide a demo such as bootply.com or jsfiddle.net with your css and html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the div to display:inline-block; in the css.

It should then get the width of the content instead of filling out the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Using `display:inline-block;` for your `.feature-text` class should solve your problem.

You can also use the Bootstrap `.btn-group` with a little bit of custom CSS to get a similar result :

```
<div class="rental-feature btn-group">
  <span class="feature-icon btn btn-default"><i class="icon-food"></i></span>
  <span class="feature-text btn btn-default">Food</span>
</div>
<div class="rental-feature btn-group">
  <span class="feature-icon btn btn-default"><i class="icon-glass"></i></span>
  <span class="feature-text btn btn-default">Glass</span>
</div>
```

```
.feature-icon,
.feature-icon:hover,
.feature-icon:focus {
  cursor: default;
  background: #ddd;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
.feature-text,
.feature-text:hover,
.feature-text:focus {
  cursor: default;
  background: white;
  border-color: #ccc;
}
```

**[Demo on Bootply](http://bootply.com/95047)**